# How to programmatically make a video from still images with sound and nice transitions in Linux

Tags: linux, perl, imagemagick

I have several folders with photos, each having 6-15 images. They are vacation photos or family gatherings etc.

I would like to write a Linux script (in shell or Perl) that creates videos from these images, using nice transitions like "page flip" or "rotate and fly away" and such.

I also want to overlay .mp3 sound over the photos.

People do this all the time with menu based video editing software, but I want to do so programmatically.

What would be your suggestion how to programmatically create a video from still images with various video effects?

I can program in Bash, Perl and C++, and I need something that can work on Linux.

Comment: Have you considered using HTML instead of creating a video file?

Comment: You could also programmatically build a PowerPoint/LibreOffice presentation with effects. You could then run it and screen-record it.

Comment: [ffmpeg + examples](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) is a start.

Comment: I found some nice and promising scripts: http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/fxtransitions/index.php

Comment: HTML, CSS and Javascript is definitely worth considering. I have done some of this type of thing with HTML and jQuery and created [a plug-in](http://grantm.github.io/jquery-title-sequence/) for coordinating  sequences. I was also able to [create a movie](http://grantm.github.io/jquery-title-sequence/#rendering) file by running  the code in PhantomJS, having it save a screenshot at intervals, and using ffmpeg to stitch the frames together.